# Where can I ask about improving an inefficient script using awk, bash, sed (32 lines so far)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a 32-line bash script with calls to sed and awk. I started writing it only to show the intended output for a question for Unix & Linux or Stack Overflow (as far as I know). The question would be how best to process a single line of comma separated floating points from an svg file - and do so efficiently. It sounds insane but the script works, and is itself part of a larger objective I have on Graphic Design - but I've already gotten the charge of "x,y" problem. I could break the script up and try doing the task with different approaches - but *discussion* - even a *bit* would help to navigate - and I know Stack Exchange is *not* about discussion. Yet, there is *something* I gather from Stack Exchange that expands/weighs the ideas - that's what I'm looking for.

[My Graphic Design Q/A post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160239/inkscape-dots-points-on-a-curve-line-x-y-coordinates-of-points-in-svg-file) where I show what I am doing and that it works.

[Code Review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283558/processing-a-very-long-single-line-of-comma-separated-floating-point-numbers) in which I put Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog's suggestion to work. Learned more sed - good for me, but not sure about anyone else.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I was unaware of Code Review! Seems appropriate to me - then I suppose each part - e.g. ```awk,sed,bash``` could *individually* be taken out to, say, Unix & Linux. So @Laurel I suppose I was asking for a review - hadn't thought of that either. I mean, the script is a cobbling together of things I know, it is not impressive.

Comment: .... and I suppose svg is best for Graphic Design... is there a web design area that understands the format, language, and so on of xml or svg files?

Comment: [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) was invented because [Larry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall) was [unhappy with those three](https://www.shlomifish.org/lecture/Perl/Newbies/lecture1/intro/history.html). [Slides](https://www.shlomifish.org/lecture/Perl/Newbies/vhll-slides.pdf).

Comment: It looks like XY Problem as the question suggests that you want to process XML with Regular Expressions which is not a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11379709

Comment: @AugustoVasques added a link to the Graphic Design which shows some of what I mean - good point about the XML, something to think about.

Answer (score -2):

I learned today that Meta Stack Exchange is, in fact, a place to ask questions about Stack Exchange, BUT [Meta Stack **Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) will *probably* be a better place to ask about Stack Overflow specifically. I am unaware of anything like Meta Code Review or other Metas of specific SEs.

Nonetheless, the comments above got me up and going to make better use of Stack Exchange, which seems to take time.